# how to change value dynamically on flutter dialog without pressing button or any thing

Tags: flutter

hi i have a CircularPercentIndicator and i put it in Dialog widget and I want to change the percent value dynamically

```
showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
      setState(() {

      });
      return Center(
          child: CircularPercentIndicator(

              radius: 45.0,
              lineWidth: 4.0,
              percent: sum/100,
              center: new Text("${sum.toInt()}"),
              animation: true,
              progressColor: Colors.orange,

          )

      );
    }

    );
```

or i need a widget like the dialog (overlay my original widget without hide it)

Comment: do you mean a percent value that changes with time?

Comment: yes dynamically

Answer (score 0):

i solve it by add stack, Opacity and ModalBarrier Widgets

```
return  Stack(
      children: [
        Scaffold(

         
        ),
        if(isLoading)
        Opacity(
          opacity: 0.8,
          child: ModalBarrier(dismissible: false, color: Colors.black),
        ),
    if(isLoading)

      Center(
          child: CircularPercentIndicator(

            radius: 45.0,
            lineWidth: 4.0,
            percent: sum >= 100 ? 1 : sum/100,
            center: new Text("${sum.toInt() }%", style:
              TextStyle(
                color: AppButtons,
                fontSize: 20,
              ),),
            progressColor: AppButtons,

          )

      ),
      ],
    );
```